# When you duplicate a simple product what do you do with the url

Tags: simple-product, product-urls

When you duplicate a simple product, what do you do with the url?

Answer (score 1):

You can let it unchanged if you want. Magento will add an entry in URL Rewrite Management for the duplicated product.

For example, the url for original product is product1, and you can access it using `{url}/product1.html`.

Then for duplicated product, Magento will generate additional number and append it to the original url to make it  unique, like `{url}/product1-2.html`.